# Using function from file in outer package

Tags: go, backend

I'm a Golang beginner here and struggling with how to use function from the outer package

Here I have the source code as this tree below

```
-samplego
--pkg
--src
---github.com
----pkg1
-----a.go
-----pkg2
-------b.go
```

In b.go, I want to use the function from a.go but the compiler told me that the function is undefined even if I declare the function as public(with first character as capital letter).

I wonder If I have to import anything from a.go before using it but I think I would get circular import because in a.go also use function from b.go.

Thank you.

Comment: There are no "outer" packages in Go. And there are no "inner" or "parent" or whatnot packages. All packages are equal. (Nitpick for the true pedantics: stdlib, internal and vendor have additional rules). if you want to use anything from a package you must import it and no, you cannot have circular imports in which case you **must** redesign.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe, a.go and pkg2 is flat, so, why don't you change your file view, like:

`-samplego
--pkg
--src
---github.com
----pkg1
-----a.go
-----b.go`

If you want keep your file structure, you should use mod, wait me some time.

`-samplego
--pkg
--src
---github.com
----pkg1
-----a.go
-----pkg2
-------b.go`

command below:
`bash
cd $(SAMPLEGO_PATH) // change path to samplego exists
go mod init samplego`

In b.go, import "samplego/src/github.com/pkg1", then import functions from a.go by pkg1.function;
In a.go, import "samplego/src/github.com/pkg1/pkg2", then import functions from b.go  by pkg2.function;

Answer (score -2):

Unfortunately, circular dependencies are not allowed until Go2. What you are trying to do can be made with the current Go version. You can refactor the code in order to create a package C that contains the data structures and the methods that have to be exported. 
Remember that you need to use the `go mod init YOUR_MODEL_NAME` and then you can call the method (remember that have to be exported) from the other file using `import YOUR_MODEL_NAME/package_name`. And remember that every folder can contain only one package.

Comment: The OP says: "In b.go, I want to use the function from a.go. in a.go also use function from b.go. I think I would get circular import." How do you answer the OP's question?

Comment: From what @peterSO said, does that mean it is impossible to do? Should I change to structure of the code instead? Do you have any suggestion? I'm confused right now :(

Comment: If is a public repo, please provide the link. Unfortunately, circular dependencies are not allowed until Go2